# ¿Por que json_length en MySQL devuelve una cantidad -1 al total de elementos del array en ciertos casos?

Tags: mysql, json

Estoy realizando con consulta select para contar el numero de elementos en un array de objetos, este array a su vez esta contenido dentro de otro array de objetos en JSON, la consulta me devuelve en la mayoría de los casos la cantidad exacta de elementos del array interno, la consulta que utilizo es la siguiente:

```
        -- CONTAR PAGOS SOLO PARA UNA POSICION DEL ARRAY DE EMPLEOS(array padre) por un persona
         SELECT 
      DATOS_ENVIADOS AS AFILIADO, json_length(DATOS_RESPUESTA->>'$.respuesta.detalladoEmpleos[1].pagos') AS NUM_PAGOS_0
         FROM CONSULTA 
          where
         TIPO_CONSULTA = 'WS_consultaDetallado' 
         and DATOS_ENVIADOS = 'CC_123456789'
         AND  FECHA between '2022-06-02 20:00:00' and '2022-06-05 09:00:00';
```

Si nos fijamos con `json_length(DATOS_RESPUESTA->>'$.respuesta.detalladoEmpleos[1].pagos') AS NUM_PAGOS_0` accedo a la columna que contiene la respuesta en JSON de la cual quiero contar la cantidad de elementos del array más interno(pagos) por el array mas externo (empleos de 1 hasta 6), aquí: `json_length(DATOS_RESPUESTA->>'$.respuesta.detalladoEmpleos[1].pagos')` accedo al array de empleos numero 5 , la tabla que gestiono tiene la siguiente estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde DATOS_RESPUESTA contiene el JSON:

```
    {
    "respuesta": {
        "detalladoEmpleos": [
            {
                "id": 1,
               "tipoIdentifiacionEmpleador": "NI",
                "identifiacionEmpleador": "123456",
                "nombreEmpleador": "NOMBRE EMPLEADOR",
                "telefonoEmpleador": null,
                "direccionEmpleador": null,
                "pagos": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 271400,
                        "fechaPago": "2022-05-05 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202204",
                        "ibc": 2360000
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 264500,
                        "fechaPago": "2022-04-21 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202203",
                        "ibc": 2300000
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 270249,
                        "fechaPago": "2022-03-22 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202202",
                        "ibc": 2350000
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 255300,
                        "fechaPago": "2022-02-09 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202201",
                        "ibc": 2220000
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 311508,
                        "fechaPago": "2022-01-04 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202112",
                        "ibc": 2708526
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 317258,
                        "fechaPago": "2021-12-09 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202111",
                        "ibc": 2758526
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 7,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 281829,
                        "fechaPago": "2021-11-09 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202110",
                        "ibc": 2450026
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 8,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 277008,
                        "fechaPago": "2021-10-27 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202109",
                        "ibc": 2408526
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 9,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 242508,
                        "fechaPago": "2021-09-09 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202108",
                        "ibc": 2108526
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 10,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 231008,
                        "fechaPago": "2021-08-19 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202107",
                        "ibc": 2008526
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 11,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 333358,
                        "fechaPago": "2021-07-01 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202106",
                        "ibc": 2898526
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
               "tipoIdentifiacionEmpleador": "NI",
                "identifiacionEmpleador": "123456",
                "nombreEmpleador": "NOMBRE EMPLEADOR",
                "telefonoEmpleador": null,
                "direccionEmpleador": null,
                "pagos": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 728672,
                        "fechaPago": "2022-06-02 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202205",
                        "ibc": 6336000
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 728751,
                        "fechaPago": "2022-05-04 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202204",
                        "ibc": 6336000
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 690000,
                        "fechaPago": "2022-04-12 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202203",
                        "ibc": 6000000
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 690000,
                        "fechaPago": "2022-03-03 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202202",
                        "ibc": 6000000
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 690000,
                        "fechaPago": "2022-02-02 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202201",
                        "ibc": 6000000
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 690000,
                        "fechaPago": "2022-01-04 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202112",
                        "ibc": 6000000
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 7,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 690000,
                        "fechaPago": "2021-12-02 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202111",
                        "ibc": 6000000
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 8,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 690000,
                        "fechaPago": "2021-11-03 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202110",
                        "ibc": 6000000
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 9,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 696900,
                        "fechaPago": "2021-10-05 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202109",
                        "ibc": 6060000
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 10,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 690000,
                        "fechaPago": "2021-09-02 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202108",
                        "ibc": 6000000
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 11,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 690000,
                        "fechaPago": "2021-08-03 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202107",
                        "ibc": 6000000
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 12,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 690000,
                        "fechaPago": "2021-07-02 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202106",
                        "ibc": 6000000
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "tipoIdentifiacionEmpleador": "NI",
                "identifiacionEmpleador": "123456",
                "nombreEmpleador": "NOMBRE EMPLEADOR",
                "telefonoEmpleador": null,
                "direccionEmpleador": null,
                "pagos": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 242943,
                        "fechaPago": "2022-06-07 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202205",
                        "ibc": 2112000
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 242943,
                        "fechaPago": "2022-05-04 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202204",
                        "ibc": 2112000
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 230000,
                        "fechaPago": "2022-04-08 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202203",
                        "ibc": 2000000
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 230000,
                        "fechaPago": "2022-03-04 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202202",
                        "ibc": 2000000
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 230000,
                        "fechaPago": "2022-02-04 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202201",
                        "ibc": 2000000
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 243800,
                        "fechaPago": "2022-01-12 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202112",
                        "ibc": 2120000
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 7,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 230000,
                        "fechaPago": "2021-12-06 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202111",
                        "ibc": 2000000
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 8,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 230000,
                        "fechaPago": "2021-11-05 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202110",
                        "ibc": 2000000
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 9,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 230000,
                        "fechaPago": "2021-10-06 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202109",
                        "ibc": 2000000
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 10,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 230000,
                        "fechaPago": "2021-09-06 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202108",
                        "ibc": 2000000
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 11,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 230079,
                        "fechaPago": "2021-08-06 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202107",
                        "ibc": 2000001
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 12,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 230000,
                        "fechaPago": "2021-07-07 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202106",
                        "ibc": 2000000
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "tipoIdentifiacionEmpleador": "NI",
                "identifiacionEmpleador": "123456",
                "nombreEmpleador": "NOMBRE EMPLEADOR",
                "telefonoEmpleador": null,
                "direccionEmpleador": null,
                "pagos": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 242943,
                        "fechaPago": "2022-05-13 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202204",
                        "ibc": 2112000
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 230000,
                        "fechaPago": "2022-04-08 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202203",
                        "ibc": 2000000
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 230000,
                        "fechaPago": "2022-03-11 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202202",
                        "ibc": 2000000
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 230000,
                        "fechaPago": "2022-02-17 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202201",
                        "ibc": 2000000
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 230000,
                        "fechaPago": "2022-01-12 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202112",
                        "ibc": 2000000
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 230000,
                        "fechaPago": "2021-12-14 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202111",
                        "ibc": 2000000
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 7,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 230000,
                        "fechaPago": "2021-11-04 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202110",
                        "ibc": 2000000
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 8,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 230000,
                        "fechaPago": "2021-10-06 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202109",
                        "ibc": 2000000
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 9,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 230000,
                        "fechaPago": "2021-09-08 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202108",
                        "ibc": 2000000
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 10,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 230079,
                        "fechaPago": "2021-08-09 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202107",
                        "ibc": 2000001
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 11,
                        "diasCotizados": 30,
                        "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 230000,
                        "fechaPago": "2021-07-07 00:00:00",
                        "periodo": "202106",
                        "ibc": 2000000
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Los resultados que me da la función ***json_length()*** sobre la respuesta json anterior es:

```
Para el empleo [0]: 11 pagos, pagos en realidad: 11,
Para el empleo [1]: 11 pagos, pagos en realidad: 12,
Para el empleo [2]: 11 pagos, pagos en realidad: 12,
Para el empleo [3]: 11 pagos, pagos en realidad: 11
```

Para otros casos es decir empleados donde los pagos son diferentes de 11 o 12 por ejemplo 7 algunos su conteo es correcto y para los otros por lo general la diferencia es de -1.

Comment: La expresión `json_length(DATOS_RESPUESTA->>'$.respuesta.detalladoEmpleos[1].pagos')` devolverá `12` la cantidad de `pagos` del elemento `detalladoEmpleos.id = 2` según el JSON de ejemplo mostrado. Vea el siguiente [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dfd5f5251b373b52d35889458224c676).

Comment: Hola @wchiquito, he revisado el dbfiddle y realmente devuelve los valores correspondientes, me podrías indicar si no es mucha molestia como puedo adaptarlo para la tabla donde tengo los registros y teniendo en cuenta que necesito aplicar esta lógica a cerca de un millón de filas que son la cantidad de empleados que tengo registrados? tengo problemas para entender la sintaxis que expones debido a que no cuento con mucha experiencia. muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de MySQL está usando?, ¿puede editar la pregunta y agregar la estructura de la tabla, más datos de pruebas y el resultado final esperado de la consulta?